# How to enable trackpad gestures in windows(bootcamp)

Tags: bootcamp, trackpad, windows, multi-touch

I have used Parallels. Windows installed in Parallel VM supports most of the trackpad gestures( including three finger ). How to enable them in Bootcamp version of Mac. Any external software to enable those features. By default, I only get these features.

[image]

Comment: there's a tutorial on [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/197485/3-tools-to-make-your-macs-hardware-work-better-in-windows-with-boot-camp/) but it requires 3rd party software

Comment: @Tetsujin those are paid. I am mean they expire after some time. Do you happen to find so other free solution?

Comment: Received wisdom is that that's the only app to do it at all.